# sed regex - convert Title Case to camelCase

Tags: regex, sed

I have some text which may have either "Regular sentence case" or "Title Case Text", and I want to convert them to titleCaseText.

Taking the example `This Is Not the Real string` with the sed command

```
s/(^|\s)([A-Za-z])/\U\2/g
```

I get the output

```
ThisIsNotTheRealString
```

How can I make the first `T` to be lowercase `t`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match the first uppercase letter with `^([A-Z])`:

```
sed -E 's/^([A-Z])|[[:blank:]]+([A-Za-z])/\l\1\U\2/g'
```

Or

```
sed -E 's/^([[:upper:]])|[[:blank:]]+([[:alpha:]])/\l\1\U\2/g'
```

Then, turn the Group 1 value to lower case, and the second group (as you are already doing) to upper case. See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/cHbGWs).

**Details**

- `^([[:upper:]])` - match the start of the line and then capture an uppercase letter into Group 1
- `|` - or
- `[[:blank:]]+` - match 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `([[:alpha:]])` - and then capture any letter into Group 2

The `\l\1` will turn the Group 1 value to lower case and `\U\2` will turn the value in Group 2 to upper case.

Answer (score 3):

one way is to use two different substitutions

```
$ s='This Is Not the Real string'
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/^[A-Z]/\l&/; s/\s([A-Za-z])/\u\1/g'
thisIsNotTheRealString

$ s='Regular sentence case'
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/^[A-Z]/\l&/; s/\s([A-Za-z])/\u\1/g'
regularSentenceCase
```

if you have mixed case input:

```
$ s='ReGulAr sEntEncE cASe'
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/^[a-zA-Z]+/\L&/; s/\s([A-Za-z]+)/\L\u\1/g'
regularSentenceCase
```